# How to remove an Element from a listbox (PrimeNg)

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I've got a listbox that i want to use to add and remove elements.

Here is my code:

```
 <p-listbox #myListbox
           [options]="myListboxValues"
           [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
></p-listbox>
```

The myListboxValues is from the type SelectItem[].
I get the default values for the list as an Object Array. I iterate over the object array and add them to the myListBoxValues.

```
public initListBox(objectArray:MyObject[]): void {
    this.myListboxValues = [];
    
    objectArray.forEach(currentObject =>{
      this.myListboxValues.push({label: currentObject.label, value: currentObject});
    });
}
```

The add function:

```
public addToList(objectToAdd: MyObject): void{
  this.myListboxValues.push({label: objectToAdd.label, value: objectToAdd});
}
```

The remove function:

```
public remove(objectToRemove: MyObject): void{
    for (let _i = 0; _i < this.myListboxValues.length; _i++) {
       if(this.myListboxValues[_i].label === objectToRemove.label) {
          this.myListboxValues.splice(_i, 1);
       }              
    }
}
```

My problem is, that if i call the remove function, the listbox does not refresh.
I have to click on it that it refresh itself.

Edit: I have the same Problem with the initListBox function. I have to click on the listbox to see the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that because Angular does not see that `myListboxValues` has been modified. Maybe you should try another way:

```
const myOtherListboxValues = this.myListboxValues;
for (let _i = 0; _i < myOtherListboxValues .length; _i++) {
   if(myOtherListboxValues [_i].label === objectToRemove.label) {
      myOtherListboxValues.splice(_i, 1);
   }              
}

this.myListboxValues = myOtherListboxValues;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that any changes that you make to an reference type data, in your example array, always make manipulation with a copy of previous value and assign new object to that variable.

So instead of doing what you do in `addToList`, try something like this and also for `remove`:

```js
public addToList(objectToAdd: MyObject): void{
  const newValue = {...this.myListboxValues}
  newValue.push({label: objectToAdd.label, value: objectToAdd});
  this.myListboxValues = newValue;
}
```

In this way you make sure that rerender will happen if object reference changes.
You just help your rendering machine with this.

Doing it in your way is not bad per se, but mutating object is always a challenge for every framework to detect.